# myeclipse 6.6 not supporting jboss 7

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, myeclipse

can somebody kindly explain to me how i can use jboss 7.1.0 as a server in myeclipse 6.6 projects since in the jboss server list, the most recent is jboss 5. i would like to know if there is any other way around this without having to update IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Try the JBOSS 5 connector. If that doesn't work, there may be a setting for deploying to a custom location - not sure as I don't have ME 6.6 installed. Right click on the project, select MyEclipse->Add/remove deployments (or something similar) then choose Custom Location or "Custom Location - suffix" to deploy to a particular folder. The suffixed choice just adds ".war" to the folder name. Once deployed that custom location should appear in the Servers view though you can't start or stop a server that way.

ME 6.6 is very old and you'd be better off upgrading to the latest GA release (12.0 or "2014") or the latest early access release (13.0 or "2015"), to get full support.

Comment: jboss 5 is also very different than jboss 7, so I would suspect you just can't do what OP is requesting.

Comment: Yeah, I would expect that also, but I thought it was worth a try. So it's custom location or an upgrade (recommended).